# Unable to fetch iam role/policy in aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I am trying fetch IAM role in aws lambda function,
like

```
const iamClient = new IAMClient({
        region: "us-west-2"
    });
const role = await iamClient.getRole({
            RoleName: roleName
        });
```

But I am getting below error,

```
"TypeError: iamClient.getRole is not a function"
```

Is there any better way to fetch IAM policy or role in aws lambda?

Comment: What is IAMClient? Are you using v2 or v3 of the AWS JavaScript SDK? I'm guessing you've imported the v3 package for IAM but are writing v2 code.

Comment: "@aws-sdk/client-iam": "^3.398.0",

Comment: Did the supplied answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the v3 SDK but writing v2 code. v2 IAM clients expose named methods such as `getRole`, `CreateUser` etc. but v3 requires you to build a 'command' object and then to `send` it via the client object. Recommend you read some of the [SDK v3 samples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/javascript_iam_code_examples.html).

Here's one such example:

```
import { GetRoleCommand, IAMClient } from "@aws-sdk/client-iam";

const client = new IAMClient({ region: "us-west-2" });

const getRole = async (RoleName) => {
  const command = new GetRoleCommand({ RoleName });
  return client.send(command);
};
```

If you prefer to use the v2 SDK then:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const iam = new AWS.IAM({ region: "us-west-2" });

const getRole = async (RoleName) => {
  return iam.getRole({ RoleName }).promise();
};
```